# Is there a standard way to detect known kernel vulnerabilities for Android devices?

Tags: android, security, linux-kernel

We are now try to do some security enhancement for our Android devices without source code because the vendor doesn't provide it. We especially are interested in kernel security.

We noted that the kernels in Android devices don't always follow Google's step to be some fixed version of Linux kernel. And we can merely know which version the kernel is.

Is there a way to check for existing kernel vulnerabilities (e.g. with CVE info)?

Thanks